# How to index Drupal Commerce 2 products for the search?

Tags: 8, commerce, search

The products in Drupal Commerce 2 could not be found through Drupal's default search form.

Modules like Commerce Search are available only for Drupal 7.

How can I index product titles or SKUs and add them to the search in Drupal 8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core search will only ever search node's and users. If you want to search other entity types, like products, use [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

Just install the module, create a server (you can use the search api db submodule if you just want to use your sql database) and create your index. You will have the option of selecting which entity types get added to the index, you probably want nodes and products. Then add which ever fields that you want to be searchable.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/catalogs/create-a-catalog) for screenshots and more info on how to take it further (like adding facets).

Comment: I did all of these steps to set up product catalog, my facets are working fine but is there a way to display products while searching through Drupal's default search form or Search API is working only with views?

Comment: You would want to use Views/Search API to replace the default search.

Comment: Thanks, I think it works fine for English but my current site is in Russian and the Search API is not working properly.
It always shows ALL indexed products no matter what characters I enter in the search form.

Comment: My problem was not in the language but in the index settings. I've chosen Fulltext in the Type of the indexed field, and now it works.

Comment: AFAIU Search API does not support i18zed sites: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/1323168